# Set row as a header Azure Data Factory [mapping data flow]

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently, I have an Excel file that I'm processing using a mapping data flow to remove some null values.

This is my input file:
[image]

and after remove the null values I have:

[image]

I'm sinking my data into a Cosmos DB but I need to change the names of the columns and set my first row as headers...

I need to do this (First row as a header) in the previous step before Sink and y Can't use the mapping option a set manually the names of the columns because maybe some of these position of columns can change

Any idea to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First row as a header can only check in dataset connection.

As a work around, you can save your excel to blob(csv format) after removing null value.

Then create a copy data activity or data flow, use this csv file as source(check first row as header), Cosmos DB as sink.

---

**Update**

Setting of sink in data flow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Data preview of sink:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried to do that but when the csv is saved, this CSV includes the names of the columns like:  _col1_, _col2_, etc